# Aggregate data frame rows based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this table

```
A B C E
1 2 1 3
1 2 4 4
2 7 1 1
3 4 0 2
3 4 8 3
```

Now, I want to remove duplicates based on column A and B and at the same time **sum up** column C. For E, it should take the value where C shows the max value. The desirable result table should look like this:

```
A B C E
1 2 5 4
2 7 1 1
3 4 8 3
```

I tried this: `df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum()['C']` but my data frame does not change at all as I am thinking that I didn't incorporate the E column part properly...Can somebody advise?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is it the table from DB? By which field you want to group rows?

Comment: I want to group by all columns except the first(pandas index) and last (non unique). At the same time the values of the last column needs to be summed, so the first data entry in aggregated form should show the value 12 in the last column (being 1 row now).

Comment: If you are using pandas can you edit your question and add columns names there? Also would be better to change the image (from the link to a real image)

Comment: @DaniilMashkin I added a better visualization. Can you review and let me know what you think?

Answer (score 0):

If the first and second rows are duplicates, we can group by them.

```
In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
   A  B  C  E
0  1  1  5  4
1  1  1  1  1
2  3  3  8  3

In [21]: df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].sum()
Out[21]: 
A  B
1  1    6
3  3    8
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

> I tried this: df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum()['C'] but my data frame does not change at all

yes, it's because pandas didn't overwrite initial `DataFrame`

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
   A  B  C  E
0  1  1  5  4
1  1  1  1  1
2  3  3  8  3
```

You have to overwrite it explicitly.

```
In [23]: df = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].sum()

In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
A  B
1  1    6
3  3    8
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Ok, then the other incompleteness is on column E. How can this be tied in with the conditions described in my original text? Based on your table, value E in the first row should be 4 and in the 2nd row should be 3. Please advise.

Comment: can you please advise me further?